# background operation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is it possible to put your app in the background, and have a counter that once expires, wakes up the app and have the app does some action? I know it's basic, but I just cant seem to have it work. Where do I put this counter + action? Under app did enter background?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this works in general:

You are allowed only to run in the background for specific tasks:

Apple doc tells which tasks that are:

One of that tasks is receiving GPS messages.

As long as you have GPS enabled and your app configured that it uses GPS for background, your app stays alive in the background.
If you disable GPS some time later it will suspend, and not wake up till the user activates it.

So to realize your problem you have to stay active in the background (e.g by reading GPS).
You can start the timer in `AppDelegate:applicationDidEnterBackground` or similar

If you need more time to shutdown, you explicitly can request for more time, there is one method for that. I dont know what happens if you request more at regulary intervals

Comment: This is correct, however you can run other background tasks for up to 10 minutes. You can get the background time remaining with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining].

Comment: so up to 10 min, I can run ANY task in the background? even if not GPS/Audio/VoIP related?

Comment: Well, I have only done this in an app I use for my own purposes. I don't know what Apple would think about it. Also, it might change from 10 min to something else in a later update (as the documentation never explicitly states that it is 10 min). But other than that, yes you can. :-)

Comment: BTW, I cant find in the docs anything related to "10 minutes" - can you please point me out to this? Thanks.

Comment: You can get the remaining time with backgroundTimeRemaining on UIApplication. If you log it, you'll see it is 10 min. I don't think the documentation ever mentions it though. That is why you shouldn't rely on it always beeing 10 min in future releases.